# WebAPI(OWIN) Global Exception Logging with CreateErrorResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

Is there anyway to capture handled exceptions when CreateErrorResponse() is used to return Error response with API methods?
I currently have registered a simple global exception loggger for any exceptions, however for some api responses including Model Filter attribute, I'm CreateErrorResponse() to return error responses but this doesn't to enter the Log() method in the Global Exception Logger.
Example usage of CreateErrorResponse in an API method :

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
```

Global Exception Logger:

```
public class GlobalExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            log.Error(context.Exception);
        }
    }
```

The only way to get Log() method to be called is rather than use CreateErrorResponse, throw an Exception instead.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should log the error and any trace info in the same negative flow where you are constructing and returning the Error Response.

Using exceptions to control application flow is bad practice, avoid it.

The global handlers use is to handle anything that you haven't already handled and should be for **Very** exceptional cases, you also log there and present the user with a generic error message, while you sort out the chaos in the back of course :)

If I misunderstood your question please correct me.